# Using methods inside EF Core queries

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I've been working with EF and EF Core for a long time, but there's something that has always given me problems, one way or the other, that is using methods inside queries, specially while mapping.

For example, right now I have this code

```
    public IEnumerable<SelectObjDTO> SelectSearch()
    {
        return Context.Usuarios.IncludePerson().ToSelectObjDTO();
    }
```

and in a different class

```
    public static IQueryable<Users> IncludePerson(this IQueryable<Usuers> Query)
    {
        return Query.Include(x => x.Persons );
    }

    public static SelectObjDTO ToSelectObjDTO(this Persons POCO)
    {
        return new SelectObjDTO()
        {
            Id = POCO.Users.FirstOrDefault().Id,
            FirstName= POCO.DocumentNumber+ " - " + POCO.FirstName + " " + POCO.LastName
        };
    }

    public static IEnumerable<SelectObjDTO> ToSelectObjDTO(this IEnumerable<Persons> Query)
    {
        return Query.Select(POCO => POCO.ToSelectObjDTO());
    }
```

The function `IEnumerable<SelectObjDTO> ToSelectObjDTO(this IEnumerable<Persons> Query)` returns an error because the `Users` is empty.

But in `IEnumerable<SelectObjDTO> ToSelectObjDTO(this IEnumerable<Persons> Query)` the query does have something inside the `Users` list.

This is this case, but before I've had other problems, for example an error from EF Core, which basically said that the context is running twice in the same query (I'm really sorry, can't remember exactly how it was), which was fixed by including whatever navigation property was being called.

Just in case, I'm using lazy loading proxies.

Thanks

Comment: Load it into memory before working on the variable.

Comment: if i load it into memory, the query will load the complete entity instead of only what i need

Answer (score 4):

`ToSelectObjDTO` is a compiled function. You need to pass an `Expression<Func<...>>` as the argument to `Select()`. You can still compile it for other uses if you need to.

```cs
    public static Expression<Func<Persons,SelectObjDTO>> SelectorFunc { get; } = POCO =>
        new SelectObjDTO()
        {
            Id = POCO.Users.FirstOrDefault().Id,
            FirstName= POCO.DocumentNumber+ " - " + POCO.FirstName + " " + POCO.LastName
        };

    public static Func<Persons,SelectObjDTO> Selector  { get; } = SelectorFunc.Compile();

    public static IQueryable<SelectObjDTO> ToSelectObjDTO(this IQueryable<Persons> Query)
        => Query.Select(SelectorFunc);
```

Comment: ToSelectObjDTO is giving me an error saying "IEnumerable<Persons> does not contain a definition for 'Select'"(dunno why).
works if i use IQueryable instead of IEnumerable, though, but i kinda need it to work in IEnumerable so i can use it in both cases

Comment: @JavierGoldman Because you can't run in memory operations on a linq statement like that, it doesn't know how to translate that to sql. That's why I suggested working with it in memory.

Comment: @Train if i use the operation inside the statement without calling a different function, it works flawlessly. the same if i do what Jeremy said with IQueryable(which is still a query, so it's not in memory).IQueryable inherits from IEnumerable so i dont get why it doesnt work like that.
I might be wrong but as far as i know it's pretty important for performance in an EF query to only get the columns you need from the DB. Specially considering i'm getting data from the Users entity, if i don't do this, i'll not only get the whole Persons entity data, but also all data from related Users

Comment: Oops, IQueryable. Updated. Of course you can use the compiled selector on an IEnumerable.

Comment: what i meant in my first comment is that i wanted to use it in IEnumerable but cant because i'm getting this error: 'IEnumerable<Persons>' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and the best extension method overload 'Queryable.Select<Persons, SelectObjDTO>(IQueryable<Persons>, Expression<Func<Persons, SelectObjDTO>>)' requires a receiver of type 'IQueryable<Persons>'
EDIT: My bad, the one i tried to use is not the compiled one.
i'm trying to use ToSelectObjDTO as it was before (with IEnumerable both in the parameter and the return type)

Comment: Forgot to clarify, the reason i need it to work with IEnumerable is for one to many relationships which are ICollection

Comment: It seems like the problem is that IEnumerable works with Func instead of Expression

Comment: Sorry maybe I should have clarified. When you work with `IEnuemerable`, it doesn't filter in the database side like `IQueriable`. When you call .select on `IEnuemerable` It pulls in all the rows from the db and then executes the filtering on the server. Currently `Query.Select(POCO => POCO.ToSelectObjDTO());` calls it on IEnumerable. That's where I made the mistake, I thought you wanted that in memory so I suggested just loading it into memory with `ToList()` and working with it like that.

Comment: Well, got it working using AsQueryable(), but i cant mark this as an answer, as i need it to work with IEnumerable.

Comment: Then you should have both an IEnumerable and IQueryable implementation. If you are claiming to require an IEnumerable because of a limitation in coding patterns of the rest of your application, then those coding patterns are the problem.

Comment: it's not so much a limitation of my coding patterns, but of EF, which makes relationships of type ICollection(thus i cant use this without using AsQueryable)